# LinqToSql - Multiple subqueries creates many roundtrips

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I've got two tables that look like this:

[alt text http://www.brettrobichaud.com/images/linq.png](http://www.brettrobichaud.com/images/linq.png)

I'm trying to generate query that includes two specific StatisticsNames for each period from ApplianceStatisticsLog. Below is the Linq query I have come up with. It works but generates a single query for the first sub-select, then one additional query for EACH record for the 2nd sub-select. Ouch, the DB roundtrips are killing me.

How can I rework this to squeeze out a single sql query?

```
from l in ApplianceStatisticsLogs
where l.ApplianceServerId > 1
orderby l.PeriodEndUtc ascending
select new
{
Time = l.PeriodEndUtc,
Stat1 = from s in ApplianceStatistics
        where s.ApplianceStatisticsLogId == l.ApplianceStatisticsLogId
          &&  s.ApplianceStatisticNameId == 2
        select s.Value,
Stat2 = from s in ApplianceStatistics
        where s.ApplianceStatisticsLogId == l.ApplianceStatisticsLogId
          &&  s.ApplianceStatisticNameId == 3
        select s.Value
}
```

Comment: @BrettRobi check my answer when you get a chance, it should work for your scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freddy was on the right track and almost had it. The solution ended up being the use of First() for each subquery. As in:

```
from l in ApplianceStatisticsLogs
where l.ApplianceServerId > 1
orderby l.PeriodEndUtc ascending
select new
{
    Time = l.PeriodEndUtc,
    Stat1 = (from s in ApplianceStatistic
            where s.ApplianceStatisticsLogId == l.ApplianceStatisticsLogId
              &&  s.ApplianceStatisticNameId == 2
            select s.Value).First(),
    Stat2 = (from s in ApplianceStatistics
            where s.ApplianceStatisticsLogId == l.ApplianceStatisticsLogId
              &&  s.ApplianceStatisticNameId == 3
            select s.Value).First()
}
```

I had neglected to mention that only one record should match in the subqueries. Thanks for the help Freddy!

Answer (score 1):

**Update (based on relation)**:

```
select new
{
Time = l.PeriodEndUtc,
Stat1 = (from s in l.ApplianceStatistics
         where s.ApplianceStatisticNameId == 2
         select s.Value
       ).ToList(),
Stat2 = (from s in l.ApplianceStatistics
         where s.ApplianceStatisticNameId == 3
         select s.Value
       ).ToList()
}
```

---

**Try**:

```
select new
{
Time = l.PeriodEndUtc,
Stat1 = (from s in ApplianceStatistics
                where s.ApplianceStatisticsLogId == l.ApplianceStatisticsLogId
                  &&  s.ApplianceStatisticNameId == 2
                select s.Value
       ).ToList(),
Stat2 = (from s in ApplianceStatistics
                where s.ApplianceStatisticsLogId == l.ApplianceStatisticsLogId
                  &&  s.ApplianceStatisticNameId == 3
                select s.Value
       ).ToList()
}
```

Comment: Almost. Using ToList() in both subqueries still generated a roundtrip for every record in the main query result. The solution was using First() instead. I should hav mentioned that only one record should match.

Comment: @brett are you sure? where you using an anonymous type on the return as in the sample? I just did some tests, and I actually can't get it to do the multiple round-trips (even without ToList - so I agree that prob has no effect) ... maybe something with the type you were assigning it to?

Comment: I actually wasn't using an annoymous type. I just made that change to simplify my sample. Do you think projecting it as a concrete type made a difference? I never considered that could make any difference in the SQL.